# playing a sound by clicking a button with mediaplayer in java in android using android studios

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, media-player

I'm trying to make a beep sound when a button is clicked using MediaPlayer. But for some reason it's not working and throwing errors. I have a wave file name beep in my raw folder, inside the res folder.

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beep);
mp.start();

}
```

Here's the error it's throwing:

```
01-10 19:11:08.507 1152-13593/? E/NuPlayerDecoder: Failed to open AudioSink on format change for OMX.google.raw.decoder (err=-19)
01-10 19:11:08.508 1152-13590/? E/NuPlayer: received error(0xffffffed) from audio decoder, flushing(0), now shutting down
01-10 19:11:08.508 13567-13581/com.example.myapplication E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -19)
01-10 19:11:08.511 13567-13567/com.example.myapplication E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-19)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you should change your sound extention**

[Refer this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats)